# Python strategy for extracting text from malformed html pages

Tags: python, html, text, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to extract text from arbitrary html pages. Some of the pages (which I have no control over) have malformed html or scripts which make this difficult. Also I'm on a shared hosting environment, so I can install any python lib, but I can't just install anything I want on the server.

pyparsing and html2text.py also did not seem to work for malformed html pages.

Example URL is http://apnews.myway.com/article/20091015/D9BB7CGG1.html

My current implementation is approximately the following:

```
# Try using BeautifulSoup 3.0.7a
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(s) 
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
c=soup.findAll('script')
for i in c:
    i.extract()    
body = bsoup.body(text=True)
text = ''.join(body) 
# if BeautifulSoup  can't handle it, 
# alter html by trying to find 1st instance of  "<body" and replace everything prior to that, with "<html><head></head>"
# try beautifulsoup again with new html
```

if beautifulsoup  still does not work, then I resort to using a heuristic of looking at the 1st char, last char (to see if they looks like its a code line # < ; and taking a sample of the line and then check if the tokens are english words, or numbers. If to few of the tokens are words or numbers, then I guess that the line is code.

I could use machine learning to inspect each line, but that seems a little expensive and I would probably have to train it (since I don't know that much about unsupervised learning machines), and of course write it as well.

Any advice, tools, strategies would be most welcome. Also I realize that the latter part of that is rather messy since if I get a line that is determine to contain code, I currently throw away the entire line, even if there is some small amount of actual English text in the line.

Comment: Well, solution non-withstanding, the news-story you linked to was great read. Some people, huh? :)

Comment: @Lesse, I guess there are also malformed people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try not to laugh, but:

```
class TextFormatter:
    def __init__(self,lynx='/usr/bin/lynx'):
        self.lynx = lynx

    def html2text(self, unicode_html_source):
        "Expects unicode; returns unicode"
        return Popen([self.lynx, 
                      '-assume-charset=UTF-8', 
                      '-display-charset=UTF-8', 
                      '-dump', 
                      '-stdin'], 
                      stdin=PIPE, 
                      stdout=PIPE).communicate(input=unicode_html_source.encode('utf-8'))[0].decode('utf-8')
```

I hope you've got lynx!

Comment: I don't have lynx =( and they will not install it. They do have ELinks installed which they told me is suppose to be similar. Looking at the ELinks documentation to see it if will work. Good to know about lynx none the less.

Comment: ELinks and Lynx kick butt. Thanks for letting me know about them.

Comment: It was born out of desperation on my side, i can tell you. I'm glad it's useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends how good the solution has to be. I had a similar problem, importing hundreds of old html pages into a new website. I basically did

```
# remove all that crap around the body and let BS fix the tags
newhtml = "<html><body>%s</body></html>" % (
    u''.join( unicode( tag ) for tag in BeautifulSoup( oldhtml ).body.contents ))
# use html2text to turn it into text
text = html2text( newhtml )
```

and it worked out, but of course the documents could be so bad that even BS can't salvage much.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup will do bad with malformed HTML. What about some regex-fu?

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> html = """<p>This is paragraph with a bunch of lines
... from a news story.</p>"""
>>> 
>>> pattern = re.compile('(?<=p>).+(?=</p)', re.DOTALL)
>>> pattern.search(html).group()
'This is paragraph with a bunch of lines\nfrom a news story.'
```

You can then assembly a list of valid tags from which you want to extract information.